# How to scrape data from HTML Table in PHP

Tags: php, html, scrape

Hey I've been trying to scrape data from an html table and I'm not having much luck.

Website: https://www.dnr.state.mn.us/hunting/seasons.html

What I'm trying to do: I want to grab the contents of the table and encode it into json like

```
['event_title' 'Waterfowl'] and ['event_date' '09/25/21']
```

but I don't know how to do this, I've tried a couple different things but in the end I can't get it to work.

Code Example (Closest I got):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$page = file_get_contents('https://www.dnr.state.mn.us/hunting/seasons.html');
$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//tbody/tr') as $tr) {
    $tmp = []; // reset the temporary array so previous entries are removed
    foreach ($xpath->query("td[@class]", $tr) as $td) {
        $key = preg_match('~[a-z]+$~', $td->getAttribute('class'), $out) ? $out[0] : 'no_class';
        if ($key === "event-title") {
            $tmp['event_title'] = $xpath->query("a", $td);
        }
        $tmp[$key] = trim($td->textContent);
    }
    //$tmp['event_date'] = date("M. dS 'y", strtotime(preg_replace('~\.|\d+[ap]m *~', '', $tmp['date'])));
    //$result[] = $tmp;
    $marray[] = array_unique($tmp);
    print_r($marray);
}
//$array2 = var_export($result);
//print_r($array2[1]);
//var_export($result);
//echo "\n----\n";
//echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: You're working too hard. Try this: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Comment: @ryantxr How would I implement this? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I have used this a few times to scrape data from sites. Unfortunately, I don't have the code any more. Look through the examples on the site.